# Applying a two step floating catchment with boundary limitations

Tags: gis-principle, mathematics

The literature states that gravity models and the two step floating catchment area (which in itself is a version of the gravity model) method for analysing the accessibility of healthcare services by populations is considered the best. There are many variations taking into account distance decay functions, travel times and supply specific weightings.

**The equation** (summarised here by Kanuganti *et al.* (2016))

[image]
[image]

My questions applies to all of them and is something I can't quite work out from the literature or the mathematics.

**Question**

If you have an island for example then this is not a problem but if you are calculating the accessibility of a county that is surrounded by other counties (which themselves have supply and population locations) then they will have an influence on the accessibility of populations near the boundary. Is it true then that you must assess all counties in the analysis otherwise your results on the periphery will be distorted?

---

**References**

*Kanuganti, S., Sarkar, A.K. and Singh, A.P., 2016. Quantifying accessibility to health care using two-step floating catchment area method (2SFCA): A case study in Rajasthan. Transportation Research Procedia, 17, pp.391-399.*

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research it turns out that there are a few techniques that can be applied to solve this which can be quite complex to explain. Essentially there are techniques to modify the 2SFCA to account for boundary effects. If you want to exclude anything outside a specific study area then you can perform edge correction to account for bias. This involves adjusting the relevant supply variable for those located near the boundary prior to running the 2SFCA.